# Changing how hyphen is interpreted in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a field that contains names with the following structure `<name>-<version>`  (e.g. `foo-1.0`).

I have the following analyzer config:

```
"settings": {
  "index": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "default": {
          "type": "snowball",
          "language": "English"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

And the following mapping:

```
"itemName": {
  "type": "multi_field",
    "fields": {
      "itemName": {
        "type": "string",
        "index": "analyzed"
      },
      "untouched": {
        "type": "string",
        "index": "not_analyzed"
      }
    }
  },
```

I'd like to be able to search for `foo-1.0` without having to quote it.  From user feedback, this is what they expect to be able to do, but unfortunately, `foo-1.0` is being interpreted as `foo NOT 1.0`.  I understand that the hyphen is equivalent to `NOT` but I naively thought it would only do this if preceded by a space (e.g. `foo -1.0`).  Is there a way to configure elasticsearch to either stop interpreting the hyphen as NOT, or to stop is splitting on the hyphen when not prefixed by a space?  Or is it something I can influence through the analyzer?

I don't know whether this will influence the answer, but I'd also like to be able to search other fields in the same query.  E.g. something like `foo-1.0 OR bar`.

Many thanks for any help.

Graham.

Answer (score 1):

You can escape `-` with backslash `\` (or when using JSON double backslash `\\`

Search for

```
"foo\\-1.0"
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  If I understand correctly, this will require me to change all clients that use this search to do the escaping (I have JavaScript and Java clients).  If possible, I'm hoping there's a solution I can use inside elasticsearch so the clients don't need to be changed and kept in sync.

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/index_name -d '{
    "mappings" : {
        "type_name" : {
            "properties" : {
                "field_name" : { "type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

After which you could use term query or querystring.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I had a look at query_string (http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-syntax) but couldn't see how that would change the processing of the hyphen.  Am I missing something?  Thanks.

Comment: If your field will always contain values that will have to be matched completely as is, it would be the best to define such field in mapping as not analyzed.